# Sort Image according to DATE and TIME inside gridview android

Tags: android, sorting, gridview, scroll, image-gallery

//The Path where my images are saving

/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraExample/JPEG_20150107_152640.jpeg

//This is one of the file path.

//I need to sort images like last taken photo as the first one to display //inside the grid view as of now images are displayed, recent photo at the //last.

Below is my code

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


        private Context context;
        private int imageWidth;
        private Activity activity;
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        public ImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> itemList,int imageWidth) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.imageWidth = imageWidth;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return this.itemList.size();
        }

        void add(String path) {
            itemList.add(path);

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return this.itemList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                imageView = new ImageView(activity);


            }
        else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

            }

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth ,imageWidth ));


            bitmap = decodeFile(itemList.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);

             imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            imageView.setOnClickListener( new OnImageClickListener(position));


            return imageView;
        }


        class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

            int position;

            public OnImageClickListener(int position){
                this.position = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ImageDisplayActivity.class);               

                intent.putExtra("position", position);    

                Log.d("ImageAdapter","Intent.putExtra ");
                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }

        public Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            try {
                File f = new File(path);     
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
                final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = reqWidth;
                final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT = reqHeight;
                int scale = 1;
                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HEIGHT)
                    scale *= 2;

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

// And Finally when I scroll my grid view . Scrolling is not so smooth. Please help me in solving two problems.

// My GridView Activity Class

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private HelperUtils utils;
    private ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private GridView gridView;
    private int columnWidth;
    private Activity activity;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        utils = new HelperUtils(this);

        InitilizeGridLayout();

        itemList = utils.getFilePaths();

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, itemList, columnWidth);

        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    }

    private void InitilizeGridLayout() {

        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, HelperAppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((HelperAppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / HelperAppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        gridView.setNumColumns(HelperAppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
        gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
        gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
        gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);


    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you sort the list before you use it to populate the grid view?

Comment: Can u provide me an example for this ?

Comment: Could you post the full grid view adapter code that you have written?

Comment: Did you sort the `itemList` before instantiating the `ImageAdapter` in your activity?

Comment: Check out my activity class . Let me know which method I have to use for sorting.

Comment: Need one more help, every time when I scroll the grid view . This method is executed. Hence making the scroll not so smooth.                                            public Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {              ..................}    . Help me running the above method in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Collections.sort(itemList);` from your `getView` method.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.d("ImageAdapter","Inside the if condition");
            imageView = new ImageView(activity);

        }
    else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
          }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth ,imageWidth ));

       // bitmap = decodeFile(itemList.get(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);

        bitmap = decodeFile(getItem(position), imageWidth, imageWidth);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Sort the list just before you populate your grid view in your onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        utils = new HelperUtils(this);

        InitilizeGridLayout();

        itemList = utils.getFilePaths();

        Collections.sort(itemList);

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, itemList, columnWidth);

        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    }
```

You could follow the example [in this link](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) by creating a list of items that contains the image file path and the image bitmap. This way, you wouldn't have to decode the bitmap everytime `getView` is called. You could just decode it once before you populate the gridview.

Since the images are sorted in ascending order, you can replace you `getItem` method with the one below:

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.itemList.get(itemList.size() - 1 - position);
    }
```

I updated the `getView` method. You should use `getItem(position)` instead of `itemList.get(position)` to decode the bitmap.

Comment: How to sort in descending order ? As of now new images are saving at the end instead of the beginning of the grid view,

Comment: After changing the code, still the result is same. I need exactly like gallery. Whenever a new photo is taken from camera. It appears at the beginning. Any further changes ?

Comment: Thank You . Its working now . Any suggestion on make scroll smooth, for the above code.

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. Are you still decoding the bitmap inside the `getView` method?

Comment: You should decode them before you populate the gridview. Refer to the link in my answer.

Comment: Just now found a bug. My grid view is perfect now. Inside grid view when I click on any item. It was opening a FullScreenImage . My fullScreenImage class accept a path of the file which is opened. The path which i'm receiving perfect. But the image displayed in imageview is always the first photo which I have taken. Not the one which I have clicked. But when I share image through gmail , image is perfectly . Because the path is right. But only when displaying in fullscreen its showing me the first photo which was taken for all gridview items,

Comment: Please post it as a new question.

Comment: Please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192797/open-full-screen-image-when-clicked-on-grid-view-android

Comment: @iRuth according to the link you post and you advice, we should decode the image before and in the link they put them in ArrayList, I guess the ArrayList is a list of custom class which has Bitmap and title right, so what if I want that ArrayList instance accessible in everywhere? Should I make it static? Because you said don't decode bitmap twice

Comment: @truongnm, what do you mean by "everywhere"?

Comment: @iRuth I mean in multiple activities. Ahh, never mind, I didn't read the hold tutorial, now I get it :v

Answer (score 0):

For making your scroll smooth you have to display the images with Picasso library, I had the same issue !