# Camera Preview is too dark in low light android

Tags: android, android-camera, preview

My camera app preview is too dark in low light. If I open my google camera it will increase brightness inside the preview so that our face is visible to take photos. But my preview is completely dark. I have handled the brightness and lightsensor. My Lightsensor works when is some light. I need to make preview is visible. Let me what should I have to handle?

```
 public void initialBrightness() {
        try {
            brightnessMode = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (brightnessMode == Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC) {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
            brightnessModeAuto = true;
        }
        Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 95);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = 100;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    }
```

I'm calling this method in onCreate method before camera preview class is called.

Comment: please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget

Comment: In my question I have cleared mentioned I'm handling the brightness. I can increase the brightness. But there is something different which is making the preview dark . Please have a look on the question once again.

Comment: @LikithTs Please post your code that shows how you set the brightness.

Comment: I have tried to increase the brightness to 255 which is maximum. But this only increases the screen brightness. I have also used light sensor. My preview will be completely dark in low light. Light Sensor wont increase the preview brightness at that time.

Comment: iRuth Please help me on this. I dont think is related to brightness, bcoz I have increased the brightness and checked. I donno why this people are down voting.

Comment: @LikithTs Have you tried [setting white balance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setWhiteBalance(java.lang.String)) or [setting the exposure compensation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation(int))?

Comment: iRuth I have set White balance to auto. I'm setting the exposure compensation like this. int index = parameters.getExposureCompensation();

            parameters.setExposureCompensation(index); . Bcoz exposure various with each phone.

Comment: If I open my google camera in low light. It will make the preview more brighter, so face will be completely visible. In the same way if I open my camera app. It wont make my preview brighter.

Answer (score 11):

To solve the problem you have to **unlock autoExposureCompensation** and **set to the MAX value**:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
 
params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMaxExposureCompensation());
 
if(params.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
 params.setAutoExposureLock(false);
}

mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

According to [Android Develop > Reference > Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setAutoExposureLock(boolean))

> Changing the white balance mode with setWhiteBalance(String) will release the auto-white balance lock if it is set.
>
> Exposure compensation, AE lock, and AWB lock can be used to capture an exposure-bracketed burst of images, for example. Auto-white balance state, including the lock state, will not be maintained after camera release() is called.
>
> Locking auto-white balance after open() but before the first call to startPreview() will not allow the auto-white balance routine to run at all, and may result in severely incorrect color in captured images.

So be careful and use the mentioned code **after** the first call to startPreview()

Comment: How can we do it if it is in camera2?

Comment: If you found an answer @ShylendraMadda I am interested in ! I have the exact same problem on CameraX new library

Answer (score 7):

Try the below code. It worked for me.

```
   previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, getRange());//This line of code is used for adjusting the fps range and fixing the dark preview
   previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, false);
   previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
```

getRange() function as belw:

```
private Range<Integer> getRange() {
    CameraManager mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    CameraCharacteristics chars = null;
    try {
        chars = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Range<Integer>[] ranges = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);

    Range<Integer> result = null;

    for (Range<Integer> range : ranges) {
        int upper = range.getUpper();

        // 10 - min range upper for my needs
        if (upper >= 10) {
            if (result == null || upper < result.getUpper().intValue()) {
                result = range;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that has worked for me so far. But the preview I'm getting looks like night mode

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me, after hours of testing with different settings was to reduce Frames per Second.

By doing so I guess the Automatic Exposure correction has enough time to compute the best settings for the available light.

So, reducing from 30 fps to 10 fps made it.

```
mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(10.0f)
            .build();
```

Comment: what is .serRequestedFps here ?

Comment: How can I set frames per miliseconds ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments, scene-mode setting can change the preview (unlike ISO or exposure-compensation, which both work for captured pictures). Don't use auto. Try scene-mode-values=night or scene-mode=dusk-dawn.

The problem with scenes is that the supported values are not standardized across devices. But some kind of night is usually present.

Comment: I have already implemented SCENE_MODE_NIGHT. And I have implemented when starting the preview. If I'm wrong correct me with some  example code.

Comment: I solved it by giving variable fps to the Camera. First call Camera.getParameter.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange(); In my case I got (15000 to 15000),(24000 to 24000),(30000 to 30000) and (15000,30000). I tried setting range from 15000 to 30000. Make sure that you are passing to different number.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the open source code of Android Camera app here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git/+/lollipop-release

It initialize the camera this way:

```
// Reset preview frame rate to the maximum because it may be lowered by
// video camera application.
 List<Integer> frameRates = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFrameRates();
        if (frameRates != null) {
            Integer max = Collections.max(frameRates);
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(max);
        }
```

And it works well in Android Nexus 5, lollipop.