# Android camera2 dummy surface does not work

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

From [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), I made a very small change that is to replace the texture surface with a dummy one:

```
private SurfaceTexture mDummyPreview = new SurfaceTexture(10);
private Surface mDummySurface = new Surface(mDummyPreview);
.........
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mDummySurface);
```

and it doesn't work anymore. When I click "Picture" it works for the first time but then it doesn't work after that.

It is supposed to work from this [os answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949873/1726452)

Do you know why is that? What am I missing here?

**UPDATED**

This error keeps coming up whenever the program take the still photo:

```
W/Binder: Binder call failed.
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CaptureCallbackHolder.getRequest(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onResultReceived(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1758)
                                                                     at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceCallbacks$Stub.onTransact(ICameraDeviceCallbacks.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add mDummySurface to the session configuration as well?  That is, to the call to CameraDevice.createCaptureSession() ?

Comment: @EddyTalvala Yes I did. I updated the question with the error message. Do you know what that error means? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include a complete logcat from a test run; it's not possible to tell what's wrong from that small snippet, unfortunately.

Comment: hi @EddyTalvala I managed to make it work now by calling mDummyPreview.setDefaultBufferSize(). But now I encounter another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198374/continuously-take-still-photo-with-android-camera2). Thanks.

Comment: I the same issue, only appear on Xiaomi Mi5 (Android 7.0)