# Camera-2 API - Getting dark Image (Almost Black) in low light

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to test camera but I am getting too dark image in low light (R<5 G<5 B<5). Please help me to figure out where am I going wrong

Initializing the camera capture callback

```
private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {

        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        if (mPicturesTaken.lastEntry() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Done taking picture from camera " + mCameraDevice.getId());
        }
        closeCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull CaptureFailure failure) {

        super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
        Log.i(TAG, "Error in Camera " + mCameraDevice.getId() + " capture session \n was image captured " + failure.wasImageCaptured() +
            "Reason for failure : " + failure.getReason() );
        closeCamera();
    }
};
```

Initializing the listener for the image availability

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imReader) {
        // Get the bytes of the image into an array
        final Image image = imReader.acquireLatestImage();
        final ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);

        // Update the list of pictures taken.
        updatePictureTaken(bytes);
        image.close();
    }
};
```

Callback for CameraManager.takeCamera()

```
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraClosed = false;

        Log.d(TAG, "camera " + camera.getId() + " opened");
        mCameraDevice = camera;

        // Delay the handler by 500 ms to take clear pictures.
        final int delay = 500;

        Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture from camera " + camera.getId());
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    takePicture();
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        Log.d(TAG, " camera " + camera.getId() + " disconnected");
        if (mCameraDevice != null && !mCameraClosed) {
            mCameraClosed = true;
            mCameraDevice.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraClosed = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "camera " + camera.getId() + " closed");
        //once the current camera has been closed, start taking another picture
        if (!mCameraIds.isEmpty()) {
            takeAnotherPicture();
        } else {
            onDoneCapturingAllPhotos(mPicturesTaken);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "camera in error, int code " + error);
        if (mCameraDevice != null && !mCameraClosed) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
        }
    }

};
```

This caprutes the images and stores the bytes. This is called from cordova plugin.

```
public void captureImagesFromCamera() {
    sResultMap.put(mCameraOrientation, false);
    sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "Capturing Image");
    Log.d(TAG, "Camera orientation = " + mCameraOrientation + " and Initial result is = "
            + sResultMap.get(mCameraOrientation));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission for camera has been granted");
        mPicturesTaken = new TreeMap<>();
        if (!mCameraIds.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "camera ids list is not empty and size = " + mCameraIds.size());

            mCurrentCameraId = mCameraIds.poll();
            Log.d(TAG, "Current camera id = " + mCurrentCameraId);

            openCamera();
        } else {
            //No camera detected!
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera list received from plugin is empty");
            onDoneCapturingAllPhotos(mPicturesTaken);
            sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "No Camera Detected!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera permissions are missing");
        sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "Camera permissions are missing");
    }
}

/**
 * Manager.openCamera() is called from here after checking for permissions.
 */
private void openCamera() {
    try {
        // This check needs to be there as it is compiler imposed
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera permissions are granted. Assigning state call back now");
            mManager.openCamera(mCurrentCameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera permissions are not granted");
            sResultMap.put(mCameraOrientation, false);
            sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "Camera permissions are not granted");
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, " exception occurred while opening camera " + mCurrentCameraId, e);
        sResultMap.put(mCameraOrientation, false);
        sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "exception occurred while opening camera");
    }
}

/**
 * Method to read the image from the camera in jpeg format  and assign the image listeners.
 *
 * @throws CameraAccessException
 */
private void takePicture() throws CameraAccessException {

    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera device is null");
        return;
    }
    final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());
    Size[] jpegSizes = null;
    StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
    if (streamConfigurationMap != null) {
        jpegSizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    }
    final boolean jpegSizesNotEmpty = jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length;
    final int width = jpegSizesNotEmpty ? jpegSizes[0].getWidth() : 640;
    final int height = jpegSizesNotEmpty ? jpegSizes[0].getHeight() : 480;
    final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);

    //Define output surfaces to host the image
    final List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, 12);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_PARTY);
    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);

    Log.d(TAG, "Will attempt to create camera capture session now");
    // Creating the picture capure session
    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces,
            new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Session capture calling");

                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, null);

                        Log.d(TAG, "Session capture called");
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, " exception occurred while accessing " + mCurrentCameraId, e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Configuration failed");
                }
            }
            , null
    );
}

// Take another pic if there is another camera.
private void takeAnotherPicture() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to take another picture");
    mCurrentCameraId = mCameraIds.poll();
    Log.d(TAG, "Current Camera id = " + mCurrentCameraId);
    openCamera();
}

private void closeCamera() {
    Log.d(TAG, "closing camera " + mCameraDevice.getId());
    if (null != mCameraDevice && !mCameraClosed) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Camera closed");
        mCameraDevice.close();
    }
    if (null != mImageReader) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image reader closed");
        mImageReader.close();
        mImageReader = null;
    }
}

/**
 * We've finished taking pictures from all cameras.
 */
private void onDoneCapturingAllPhotos(TreeMap<String, byte[]> picturesTaken) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Capturing all images done. Currently no non-black pixel found");
    sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "Reading Capturted Image!");
    boolean foundNonBlackPixel = false;
    long imageProcessingStartTime = System.nanoTime();

    Log.d(TAG, "Pictures taken is null? = " + (picturesTaken == null) + "Is picture taken empty? = " + picturesTaken.isEmpty());
    if (picturesTaken != null && !picturesTaken.isEmpty()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Iterate over all pictures");
        StringBuffer description = new StringBuffer("");
        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entryMap : picturesTaken.entrySet()) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Compressing image");
            // Get the byte stream from bytes array to decode into bitmap.
            final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(entryMap.getValue());
            final BitmapFactory.Options largeOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // This makes sure only bitmap information is fetched and not the bitmap itself.
            largeOption.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, largeOption);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int requiredWidth = 200;
            final int requiredHeight = 200;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (largeOption.outWidth / scale >= requiredWidth && largeOption.outHeight / scale >= requiredHeight) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            Bitmap bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entryMap.getValue(), 0, entryMap.getValue().length);

            int width = bitmapLarge.getWidth();
            int height = bitmapLarge.getHeight();

            // Scale down the bitmap to iterate over all pixels.
            int scaledWidth = 160;
            int scaledHeight = ((160 * height) / width);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapLarge, 160, ((160 * height) / width), true);

            description.append("\n Bitmap width = " + scaledWidth + " and height = " + scaledHeight + "\n");
            foundNonBlackPixel = false;
            for (int x = 0; (x < scaledWidth && !foundNonBlackPixel); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; (y < scaledHeight && !foundNonBlackPixel); y++) {
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Pixel value = " + pixel);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Max Red pixel value = " + Color.RED);
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
                    // A range of 5 is allowed to determine black pixels.
                    if (!(redValue <= 5 && blueValue <= 5 && greenValue <= 5)) {
                        foundNonBlackPixel = true;
                        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                        description.append("Camera pixel :  Red color = " + redValue + " Green color = " +
                                greenValue + " Blue color = " + blueValue + " found non black pixel = " + foundNonBlackPixel +
                                "\n Total Time Taken = " + (cameraTestStartTime - endTime) +
                                "ns \n Time Taken to Capture Image = " + (cameraTestStartTime - imageProcessingStartTime) +
                                " \n Time Taken to find Non Black Pixel = " + (imageProcessingStartTime - endTime));
                        sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, description.toString());

                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera pixel :  Red color = " + redValue + " Green color = " +
                            greenValue + " Blue color = " + blueValue + " found non black pixel = " + foundNonBlackPixel);
                }
            }

            if (foundNonBlackPixel) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Putting " + foundNonBlackPixel + " into " + mCameraOrientation);
    sResultMap.put(mCameraOrientation, foundNonBlackPixel);
    if (!foundNonBlackPixel) {
        sResultDescriptionMap.put(mCameraOrientation, "Found All Black Pixels!");
    }
}

private void updatePictureTaken(final byte[] bytes) {
    mPicturesTaken.put(mCurrentCameraId, bytes);
}
```

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429071/camera-preview-is-too-dark-in-low-light-android/49643140#49643140