# Image View is opening a wrong image when clicked on thumbnail image in grid view android

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have some images which is displayed in grid View. If I click on thumbnail image in grid view sometimes it opens a wrong image.

Please note: Not all the time.

This issue i'll face only when I take a picture and goto grid View and trying to open the image which I recently took. For example I have 99 images in grid view and I take 100th photo from my camera app. When I click on 100th image in grid view. It opens the 98 or 97th photo, not the one which I clicked. And it happens vice-verse also. But rest all the thumbnail images are opening fine.

My RecyclerViewAdapter class

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(getItem(position))));
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);

        Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext())
                .load(uri)
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
    }

    class OnImageClickListener extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        int position;

        public OnImageClickListener(int position){
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected int getLayoutResource() {
            return R.layout.activity_recycleview;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ImageDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", getPosition(position));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.itemList.get(getPosition(position));
    }

    public int getPosition(int position) {
        return itemList.size() - 1 - position;
    }
```

My FullScreenImageAdapter class

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView imageView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);

        imageView = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(imagePaths.get(position))));

        // If Check the path here I'm getting the path which image view is displaying, not the image path which I clicked.

        Picasso.with(container.getContext())
                .load(uri)
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `imagePaths` in FullScreenImageAdapter class and `itemList` in RecyclerViewAdapter  class are same? Do you update the other list when the first list is upadted?

Comment: If the path was wrong it should have not worked for rest of the images inside the grid view. It happens only for one or two images and works fine rest of the images.

Comment: Yeah..if you add 2 extra images only in first list and second list doesn't have those images, the second list will point to different images than the first.

Comment: Just to be sure log/print the size of both lists and make sure both the lists have same size.

Comment: In a brief can you tell me about first list and second list concept? If this the problem who can I correct it?

Comment: I have a separate class which handles the list. grid view and image view is a two different activity for me. So every time I start a activity I read the list of images which is stored in the separate folder inside the gallery.

Comment: Pass the arraylist along with intent so that you can use the same arraylist in next activity.

Comment: I'm doing as you directed.  intent.putExtra("list",itemList); adding this in recycler view adapter. And in my Image display activity I'm retrieving like this.  imagePaths = i1.getExtras().getStringArrayList("list"); . As of now i'm not facing a problem. Is this a permanent fix?

Comment: Hmm.. if this fixes the issue then i guess the problem was due to different list in different activities. There is a limit on how much data you can send through intent. As long as  the list doesn't grow tooo big there shoudn't be any problem. Or else you can think of any other approach to maintain consistent list across the activities,.

Comment: suppose if the list exceeds 1000+ images. Problem is going to repeat ?

Comment: Not the same problem.But app may crash with TransactionTooLargeException..So I don't suggest to pass such large arrays through intent.